# Heroku failing to seed photos. I am using paperclip and imagemagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

here is my photo model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :trip_info

  has_attached_file :avatar,
                    :styles => { :medium => "310x300#>",
                                 :thumb => "100x100#>",
                                 :city => "260x250#",
                                 :large => "500x300#"
                                },
                    :default_url => "/images/:style/logo3.png"

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

In my production.rb and development.rb file:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

When I type in which convert in my terminal, I see:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert
```

When I try to push to heroku, I get this error message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Avatar There was an error processing the thumbnail for 2226e4749f8e482e24c4c2d9902e3b5120150403-3-1taxt3u, Avatar There was an error processing the thumbnail for 2226e4749f8e482e24c4c2d9902e3b5120150403-3-1taxt3u
```

Aragh Heroku... what do I do to push up and seed my database? These errors occur when I am trying to run heroku run rake db:seed.

Comment: Are you sure the imagemagick binaries are  installed in /usr/local/bin on heroku?

Comment: It's something with ImageMagick on heroku side. Have you checked this: https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/heroku.html